# What does ":" for this code snippet mean in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a code snippet like this in app.component.html

```
[ngClass]="{odd:odd%2!==0}"
```

odd is defined in style like this

```
.odd
{
color:red;
}
```

can you give me what [ngClass]="{odd:odd%2!==0}" mean

Comment: It means give the class `odd` to the component it's attached to  once the following condition met `odd % 2 !== 0`

Comment: you forget enclosed between quotes the name of the class: `[ngClass]="{'odd':odd%2!==0}"`